# Define position of line by parameters (Tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

It is possible to give in the coordinate of the point by an outside variable?

For example, I have a simple line:

```
\begin{document}

\draw (0,0) -- (5,5);

\end{document}
```

I would like to parametrize the x-coordinate, such as:

```
\begin{document}

*(some command that defines y)* y = 10;

\draw (0,y) -- (5,5+y);

\end{document}
```

I am familiar with the command coordinate:
[Define a variable in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12859/define-a-variable-in-tikz)

But with it I need to add coordinate of the point. I would like to parametrize one coordinate.

Reason?

I have two drawings in the same Tikz picture, one above the other. It is very likely that I will want to adjust the distance between them. The solution above would enable me to simply "shift" one of the figures up or down by changing the value of y associated with every y coordinate.

Comment: Use a scope around the second and `shift` it. For example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238330/tikz-problems-with-relative-position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the answers to the question you linked, you can do that. Just define a macro outside of the tikz environment. You can then use this macro in each of the multiple tikz pictures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\myvalue}{10}

First Tikz Picture

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,\myvalue) -- (5,5+\myvalue);
\end{tikzpicture}

Second Tikz Picture

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,\myvalue) -- (1,1+\myvalue);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, if you define two `tikzpicture` environments, there's no need for this shift, because they won't overlap by default. The shift would make sense in the same picture. cc @nevermind

Comment: @Alenanno You are right. I haven't really read what his goal is. I just read his original question about how to define an "outside" variable.

Comment: I need both figures in the same environment because they are related and I am drawing some lines from the "top" one to the "bottom" one, so Benjamin's answer is precisely what I needed. Although, of course, I can define \myvalue inside the environment.