# Alternatives to watermark

Tags: watermark

Are there any alternatives to watermark  ie something that looks nice overlayed on top of text but with something like a stamp or a seal for instance ?

Comment: `background` package, for example. A watermark isn't overlaid, actually

Comment: but with background, you have to insert a picture etc - I want to have something that one can use as simple as the watermark

Comment: No, you can put anything into the background -- the `contents=...` option can contain anything, basically!

Comment: ok - see what you mean ie like this [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244091/watermark-using-background-package-in-beamer]. do you happen to have any other nice example with something more artistic ?

Comment: Well, 'draft' isn't artistic really :D See my answer here (and decide whether it's artistic at all ;-)) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296183/grid-a-single-page

Answer (score 2):

Since `background` is a `TikZ` package already, anything possible with TikZ is also possible for `background`

Here's just an example

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{background}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\bgcontentsstuff}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \shade[ball color=red] (-0.5\textwidth,-0.5\textheight) rectangle(0.5\textwidth,0.5\textheight+1em);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\backgroundsetup{contents={\bgcontentsstuff},scale=1,angle=0}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: background internally puts the content in a node in a tikzpicture. So you are actually nesting tikzpictures, something that should be done with care see e,g, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238332/2388, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66037/2388. E.g. page coordinates won't work correctly. For this reason I prefer eso-pic if the content is a tikzpicture.